# Is sizeof converted to a constant number after compilation?

Tags: c++, compilation, sizeof

Are these equal speed-wise?

```
return someNumber / sizeof(myStruct); // Pretend sizeof returns 88 always.
```

and

```
return someNumber / 88;
```

I'm unsure if the compiler calculates sizeof every single time or writes a constant (thus making it safe for me to include sizeof() instead of a constant).

Comment: do not worry about the performance of sizeof

Comment: `sizeof` is a compile-time operator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. The compiler knows `sizeof(myStruct)` at compile-time, and will replace it with the appropriate constant.

This is always true for `sizeof` expressions in C++.

Note: this means that, for example, `sizeof(a++)` will *not* increment `a`.

Comment: I feel as though one must cross one-self anytime `sizeof(a++)` is uttered...truly hideous.